# D3: Mouseover to display data in top right corner

Tags: d3.js

I'm working in D3 with a tooltip in a mouseover event. What I have is the data displayed slightly to the right and above the dot. However, it's a line graph and this is sometimes unreadable. What I would like is the data displayed in some fixed position (I've decided the upper right hand corner is free of clutter). Can anyone give me some advice? Code below

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "red");

      tooltip.transition()
           .duration(200)
           .style("opacity", .9);

      tooltip.html("(" + xTemp(d) 
      + ", " + yTemp(d)+ ")")
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
```

Comment: You could replace `(d3.event.pageX + 5)` with fixed upper right `X_pos` and  `(d3.event.pageY - 28)` with `Y_pos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your tooltip is a `<div>` with `position: absolute`.

In that case, you can wrap your SVG in a container div (since SVGs don't support `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`) and set the position of your tooltip using [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft).

Here is a simple demo. I put two paragraphs ("Foo" and "Bar"), so you can see that the position of the `<div>` is correct, even if the SVG is not the first element on the page:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(50, 300, 50))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", Number)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "teal")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
    tooltip.html(d)
      .style("top", svg.node().parentNode.offsetTop + 10 + "px")
      .style("left", svg.node().parentNode.offsetLeft + 270 + "px")
      .style("opacity", .9);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "teal")
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
  })
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  broder: 1px solid black;
  background-color: tan;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
<div>
  <svg id="svg"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello; I'm sorry this took so long to respond. This worked great. Thanks.